# Why does the Dawnguard attack me on sight?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I joined volhikar and become a vampire.

Yes. I am their enemy.

But what actually triggers them to hate me?

Is this because I am a 4th stage vampire? Does that mean if I drink blood I can come to Dawnguard fort and buy spells?

Is this because they know that the dragon born is an evil vampire that will kill them. Then why don't they tell everyone.

I am at destroy Dawnguard quest.

All guides say that I should cast harmony if I want to buy spells from them. Why?

Update: 4th stage vampire is NOT the problem. I feed on people. I talked with normal people normally. Yet dawnguard girls still hate me.

The most likely answer is that dawnguard can know my faction. However, this is very unusual. I joined stormcloack faction. I can go to imperial camps and they do NOT attack me on sight.

Answer (score 4):

> What actually triggers them to hate me?

The game's [factions system](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions) controls whether another faction or group of NPCs hates (or likes) the player character. The [player character](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Prisoner) is always a member of the "[PlayerFaction](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions_P#PlayerFaction)" faction. I believe certain quest parts will have scripts that trigger this change in combat reaction, by setting how other factions react to the "PlayerFaction" faction.

Since you are already doing the Volkihar Clan's "Destroying the Dawnguard" quest, then members of the Dawnguard faction (and other related factions) have already been set to be [aggressive](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:NPCs#Aggression) to you.

From the UESP Wiki's "**[Factions](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Factions)**" article:

> Almost all NPCs and creatures in Skyrim belong to one or more factions (or guilds). These faction memberships control the combat reaction of all NPCs and creatures, both towards you and towards one another. You can be a member of more than one faction at a time.

Comment: If I joined stormcloack. Imperial camps do not attack me on sight. It seems that this is new to dawnguard

Comment: @user4951 It depends on the script attached to the related quests. Some quests will make certain factions aggressive, some friendly, and some will be neutral.

Answer (score -1):

According to

https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dawnguard_(faction)

> Banishment If you become a member of the Volkihar Vampire Clan by
> accepting Harkon's offer, you will be labeled an enemy of the
> Dawnguard. You will not be able to use any of the Dawnguard's services
> and will be attacked on sight by members even if you choose to cure
> your vampirism. This can be remedied somewhat by destroying the
> Dawnguard.

So this is actually very lore unfriendly. I became a vampire lord far away from them. They do not know I "sided" with Harkon. If fact, I didn't "side" with Harkon. I just chose to be vampire lord.

If I become a vampire lord latter, they will still be friendly to me. I just need to cure my self from vampirism.

So obviously the best way to be vampire lord and do dawnguard guest is to just join dawnguard and get vampire lord form from Serena.

If there is a mod that fix this it'll be great. It'll be great to do both quest lines that often intersect anyway

According to
https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/f/p/1910684946268161994

doing this will help. I haven't tried. So I am not sure.

```
completequest DLC1VampireBaseintro

set DLC1IntroCompletedVampire to 0

set DLC1PlayingVampireLine to 0

resetquest DLC1vq02

setstage DLC1VQ02 190

setstage DLC1VQ02 200

completequest DLC1vq02

setstage DLC1HunterBaseIntro 20
```